# Trying to add g++ to path

Tags: c++, path, environment-variables, g++

Hi I'm trying to learn C++ and tried adding G++ to path using MSYS2.
I've installed all packages and have added it to path using C:\msys64\mingw64\bin.
I thought this would work but cmd still doesn't recognise it as a command. Anyone know why this is or if it would just be easier to use Visual Studio code?

Comment: windows or linux? What do you get when you print your path?

Comment: After you edit your OS `PATH` environment variable you will need to restart your cmd.exe window and likely explorer for the change to take effect. You may want to logout then log back in.

Comment: If you are using msys2 you can compile from the mingw64 terminal and it should just work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, I'm using windows, I've restarted my cmd and explorer and signed out and in and still nothing, I might just compile from the mingw64 terminal instead. Wish I could figure it out though

Comment: This is my path, could it be because I have 2 accounts on this laptop?PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

Comment: ***could it be because I have 2 accounts on this laptop?*** How did you change the OS path environment variable? Here is a link to help: [https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#windows10](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#windows10)

Comment: I changed the user variable path and added C:\msys64\mingw64\bin as its where the g++ function is installed. I've followed 2 guides and gotten nowhere, should I have changed the system variables instead? let me know if i've missed anything and thank you for helping me and my noob questions.

Comment: You can do either however if you changed the path for one user account that change will not be seen in the other user's account. If you change the system PATH environment variable the change will be seen for all accounts on the PC.

Comment: Well I just changed it to the system variables and it worked! Thank you so much for your help, was probably because I've got 2 accounts, one with admin and one without.